# Multiple fields_for not working properly in active admin rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

I am making a form in active admin but field_for for is not showing multiple nested attributes.

Here is my code:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Application do
    actions :all, :except => [:destroy]

    permit_params :agent_code, :operator_id,
                    customer_attributes: [:email, person_attributes:[:name, :title_type, :first_name, :middle_name, 
                        :last_name, :id_type, :id_number, :birthday, :home_phone, :mobile_phone, :work_phone], next_of_kin_attributes:
                        [:first_name, :last_name, :home_phone]]

    form do |f|

      f.inputs "Your Details" do
        f.input :agent_code
        f.input :operator_id, as: :select, prompt: "Operator", collection: Operator.all
        f.fields_for :customer do |customer|
            customer.fields_for :person do |person|
                person.input :name, as: :hidden
                person.input :title_type, as: :select, prompt: "Title", class: 'selectpicker', collection: Person::TITLE_TYPES.map{|title_type| [ title_type[1], title_type[0] ]}
                person.input :first_name
                person.input :middle_name
                person.input :last_name
                person.select :id_type, as: :select, collection: Person::ID_TYPES.map{|id_type| [ id_type[1], id_type[0] ]} , prompt: 'ID Type', class: 'id_select_box'
                person.input :id_number
                person.input :birthday
                person.input :home_phone
                person.input :mobile_phone
                person.input :work_phone

            end
            customer.input :email
            customer.fields_for :next_of_kin do |next_of_kin|
                next_of_kin.input :first_name
                next_of_kin.input :last_name
                next_of_kin.input :home_phone
            end
        end
      end
      f.actions
    end  
end
```

In the above code when I wrote Person attributes it was visible on the front end but when I wrote next_of_kin_attributes the latter is displayed but the former is not. So basically I need to figure out How do we do multiple level of nested attributes in active admin.

If I write customer_attributes `attributes(:email)` in between of two fields for, it does not display either of the two fields_for attributes.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you figure this out i have the same issue ?

Comment: No. This was an issue with the active admin version i guess